# Does Aurelia support injection of multiple members to array

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

Does Aurelia (to be exact [aurelia-dependency-injection](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection)) support injection of multiple members to array (like [multi inject feature of InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/multi_injection.md))?

Example:

provider-common.ts:

```
class A { ... }
```

provider1.ts

```
let a1 = new A (...)
container.registerInstance(A, a1)
```

provider2.ts

```
let a2 = new A (...)
container.registerInstance(A, a2)
```

consumer.ts

```
@inject(A)
class B {
  constructor (multipleAInstancesFromDiffirentProviders :Array<A>) {
      // I would expect multipleAInstancesFromDiffirentProviders to contain [a1,a2] (if such a feature is supported)
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to understand why this question is downvoted.

Comment: Could you write an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @FabioLuz of course.

Comment: I think it's possible but I don't know how to do this yet. I'll take a look in the source-code and try to find some way to do this. In the meantime, you can encapsulate your array in a class and then inject this class to get the values

Comment: @FabioLuz thanks for attention to this question. Encapsulation would not help here. Lets say a1 and a2 are complex configuration objects. Constructor of class B does some initialization based on it. In case the array would be encapsulated in a class (having method addConfigurationObject(config:A)) we could not guarantee that all the configuration objects would be added before the constructor of A is called. It could be called with partial configuration, like {configurationObjects:[a2]}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `All.of(A)`:

```
    import {inject, All} from "aurelia-framework";

    @inject(All.of(A))
    class B {
        constructor (multipleAInstancesFromDiffirentProviders :Array<A>) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use `All.of(A)`.

You can also use this alternative:

```js
import { Container } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Container)
class B {
    constructor (container: Container) {
      var multipleAInstancesFromDifferentProviders : Array<A> = container.getAll(A);
    }
}
```